# Webpack postcss-loader causing a sass error

Tags: css, webpack, sass, tailwind-css, postcss-loader

I'm trying to include Tailwind CSS within my WordPress setup, which means I have to use post CSS. However when I add the postcss-loader to this rule:

```
{
        test: /\.(sass|scss)$/,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'sass-loader', 'postcss-loader']
},
```

I am returned the following error:

```
[./src/sass/style.scss] 1.37 KiB {frontend} [built] [failed] [1 error]

ERROR in ./src/sass/style.scss
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Invalid CSS after "...m\\[focus-within": expected selector, was "]\\:sr-only[focus-wi"
        on line 35881 of /Users/user/Local Sites/episteme/app/public/wp-content/themes/_s/src/sass/style.scss
>>   .sm\[focus-within]\:sr-only[focus-within] {

   --^

    at /Users/user/Local Sites/episteme/app/public/wp-content/themes/_s/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:316:20
    at /Users/user/Local Sites/episteme/app/public/wp-content/themes/_s/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:367:11
    at /Users/user/Local Sites/episteme/app/public/wp-content/themes/_s/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:233:18
    at context.callback (/Users/user/Local Sites/episteme/app/public/wp-content/themes/_s/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
    at Object.callback (/Users/user/Local Sites/episteme/app/public/wp-content/themes/_s/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/index.js:73:7)
    at Object.done [as callback] (/Users/user/Local Sites/episteme/app/public/wp-content/themes/_s/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:8069:18)
    at options.error (/Users/user/Local Sites/episteme/app/public/wp-content/themes/_s/node_modules/node-sass/lib/index.js:294:32)
 @ multi ./src/index.js ./src/sass/style.scss frontend[1]
Child mini-css-extract-plugin ../../../../../../../Local Sites/episteme/app/public/wp-content/themes/_s/node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!../../../../../../../Local Sites/episteme/app/public/wp-content/themes/_s/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js!../../../../../../../Local Sites/episteme/app/public/wp-content/themes/_s/node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js!../../../../../../../Local Sites/episteme/app/public/wp-content/themes/_s/src/sass/style.scss:
    Entrypoint mini-css-extract-plugin = *
    [./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js!./src/sass/style.scss] ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src!./src/sass/style.scss 368 bytes {mini-css-extract-plugin} [built] [failed] [1 error]
    
    ERROR in ./src/sass/style.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src!./src/sass/style.scss)
    Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
    SassError: Invalid CSS after "...m\\[focus-within": expected selector, was "]\\:sr-only[focus-wi"
            on line 35881 of /Users/user/Local Sites/episteme/app/public/wp-content/themes/_s/src/sass/style.scss
    >>   .sm\[focus-within]\:sr-only[focus-within] {
    
       --^
```

I've tried many different approaches and none of them seem to be working. Not sure if I'm misunderstanding something as most of the material I've found is geared towards React setups.

Answer (score 2):

Managed to resolve the issue by changing the order of the loaders to the following:

```
      {
        test: /\.(sass|scss)$/,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'postcss-sass-loader', 'sass-loader']
      },
```